# Touch events with D3.js and TUIO

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, multi-touch

I have my D3 Map which will show several data and right now I'm stuck with the implementation of multi touch and the [d3.slider](http://thematicmapping.org/playground/d3/d3.slider/) and in general touch events. This [video](https://vimeo.com/151535316) shows what it does right now. I can spawn points with the d3 slider and pan around the map. All this was achieved by using [Caress-server](https://github.com/ekryski/caress-server/) and [Caress-client](https://github.com/ekryski/caress-client/). The touch table is a Samsung SUR40 which is using [Reactivision](http://reactivision.sourceforge.net/). I get the touches as you see I can pan an I also can zoom. But the slider won't revert and I can'T see why. the d3.slider.js is modified slightly so it can react to `.on("drag)` and not `.on("click")`. Since i changed nothing else I'm confused. The slider is still working though if you use mouse only but with Multitouch/TUIO you just can slide forward with the handle but not backwards.

This is the slider/filter function which is also looking for the current viewport in my main js script:

```
var slider = d3.slider()
    .axis(false).min(minDate).max(maxDate).step(secondsInDay)
    .value(minDate)
    .on("slide", function(evt, value) {
      // console.log("SLIDE");
      // console.log(d3.touch);

    temp = moment(value,"x").utc().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    tempVal = moment(temp).unix()*1000;


      if( filterCheck == 0 ){

        if( zoomCheck == 0 ){

          newDataW = site_dataW.features.filter(function(d){

            dataDate = moment(d.properties.date).utc().unix()*1000;
            // console.log("dataDate " + new Date(dataDate));
            // console.log("slidDate " + new Date(value));
            //console.log("-- " + moment(dataDate).toDate());


            if (dataDate == tempVal) {
              //console.log("Sucess");
              //console.log(moment(dataDate).toDate());
              return moment(dataDate).toDate();
            }
          });
          showWorldSite(newDataW)

        }

        else if( zoomCheck == 1 ){

          newDataG = site_dataG.features.filter(function(d){
            dataDate = moment(d.properties.date).utc().unix()*1000;
            //console.log(value);
            if (dataDate == tempVal) {
              //console.log("Sucess")
              return moment(dataDate).toDate();
            }
          })
          showGermanSite(newDataG);
        }

        else if( zoomCheck == 2 ){

          newDataS = site_dataS.features.filter(function(d){
            dataDate = d.properties.Date;
            if (dataDate == temp) {
              return moment(dataDate).toDate()
            }
          });

          showSyrianSite(newDataS);
        }

      }
//================================================================================================
//================================================================================================
//================================================================================================

      else if( filterCheck == 1 ) {
      //
        if( zoomCheck == 0 ){

          newDataW = site_dataW.features.filter(function(d){

            dataDate = moment(d.properties.date).utc().unix()*1000;

              //console.log(new Date(dataDate) < new Date(value));
              return moment(dataDate).toDate() < moment(tempVal).toDate() ;



          });
          //console.log(newDataW.length);
          showWorldSite(newDataW)

        }
      //
        else if( zoomCheck == 1 ){

          newDataG = site_dataG.features.filter(function(d){
            dataDate = moment(d.properties.date).utc().unix()*1000;
            //console.log(moment(dataDate).toDate());
            return moment(dataDate).toDate() < moment(tempVal).toDate() ;
          })
          // console.log(newDataG.length);
          // console.log(new Date(value));
          showGermanSite(newDataG);
        }

        else if( zoomCheck == 2 ){

          newDataS = site_dataS.features.filter(function(d){
            // dataDate = moment(d.properties.Date).utc().unix()*1000;
            dataDate = d.properties.Date;
            // return dpS(d.properties.Date) < new Date(value);
            // return moment(dataDate).toDate() < moment(tempVal).toDate() ;
            // return moment(dataDate).isBefore(tempVal);
            return new Date(dataDate) < new Date(temp);
          });

          showSyrianSite(newDataS);
        }

      }





    });


d3.select('#slider3').call(slider);
```

If you want to try this at home you can download Caress Server and start it up. [Tongseng](https://github.com/fajran/tongseng) if you got OSX and if you want to use your DROID or IOS device you can downoad TUIODROID or TUIOpad. You can download all data from [my repo](https://github.com/RitterLean/TUIO-Multitouch-D3). I'd appreciate every help and tip I can get because this project is very important to me.

Answer (score 1):

The slider was not centered so every time i moved back the finger left the slider handle and was not on the handle anymore. So i got this in my css file to fix this. Now it is possible to move the slider with multitouch events too

```
.d3-slider-horizontal .d3-slider-handle {
    top: -.3em;
    margin-left: -5.5em;
    /*half of the slider handle*/
}
```